# How to run .sh file on Windows10 startup

Tags: windows, bash, shell

How to run a Bash script when starting Windows 10?

I can only find soulations for ubuntu.

Thanks.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Desktop PATH
Desktop=/c/Users/118883/Desktop
# folder with the script
executeFolder=Clean-up-folder-structure 


# mainfolder
sortingFolder=sorting

# inner folders
docFolder=1.word_docs
excelFolder=2.excel_docs
imageFolder=3.images

cd $Desktop

# moves all folders from desktop to a sorting folder
function moveMyFiles(){
find *  -mindepth 0 -maxdepth 0 -not -name $sortingFolder -not -name 
$executeFolder -exec mv -v -t $sortingFolder {} +
}

# Sort al the .docx files
function sortDocs(){
cd $sortingFolder
if [ -d $docFolder ]
then 
    find *.docx -mindepth 0 -maxdepth 0 -exec mv -v -t $docFolder {} +
else
    mkdir $docFolder
    find *.docx -mindepth 0 -maxdepth 0 -exec mv -v -t $docFolder {} +
fi
}

function sortExcel(){
cd $sortingFolder
if [ -d $excelFolder ]
then 
    find *.xlsx -mindepth 0 -maxdepth 0 -exec mv -v -t $excelFolder {} +
else
    mkdir $excelFolder
    find *.xlsx -mindepth 0 -maxdepth 0 -exec mv -v -t $excelFolder {} +
fi
}

function sortImages(){
cd $sortingFolder
if [ -d $imageFolder ]
then 
    find *.PNG -mindepth 0 -maxdepth 0 -exec mv -v -t $imageFolder {} +
    find *.JPEG -mindepth 0 -maxdepth 0 -exec mv -v -t $imageFolder {} +
    find *.jpeg -mindepth 0 -maxdepth 0 -exec mv -v -t $imageFolder {} +
    find *.jpg -mindepth 0 -maxdepth 0 -exec mv -v -t $imageFolder {} +
    find *.GIF -mindepth 0 -maxdepth 0 -exec mv -v -t $imageFolder {} +
else
    mkdir $imageFolder
    find *.PNG -mindepth 0 -maxdepth 0 -exec mv -v -t $imageFolder {} +
    find *.JPEG -mindepth 0 -maxdepth 0 -exec mv -v -t $imageFolder {} +
    find *.jpeg -mindepth 0 -maxdepth 0 -exec mv -v -t $imageFolder {} +
    find *.jpg -mindepth 0 -maxdepth 0 -exec mv -v -t $imageFolder {} +
    find *.GIF -mindepth 0 -maxdepth 0 -exec mv -v -t $imageFolder {} +
fi
} 

#main execute 
if [ -d $sortingFolder ]
then 

cd $Desktop
moveMyFiles
sortDocs
sortExcel
sortImages

else

# zo niet maak een folder
cd $Desktop
mkdir $sortingFolder
moveMyFiles
sortDocs
sortExcel
sortImages
fi
```

When running in Powershell error appear.
syntax errors and parse errors.
like:

At line:1 char:3
+ if [ -d $sortingFolder ]
+   ~
Missing '(' after 'if' in if statement.
At line:1 char:5
+ if [ -d $sortingFolder ]
+     ~
Missing type name after '['.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingOpenParenthesisInIfStatement

Comment: Bash scripts are Unix.  Why would you want to run one on a Windows system?

Comment: Windows 10 has a option to enable bash.

Comment: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-run-sh-or-shell-script-file-in-windows-10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the same as gazzo, but not with powershell, rather with a virtual shell such as git bash. If possible of course.

Due to how our environments set up at work, i use bash scripts through git bash to download git repositories, setup projects dynamically etc. You could set up windows to run git bash exe and pass in your bash script's path to run it.

Answer (score 1):

maybe a bit complicated but it works: you can run the sh script in powershell using

`sh yourShScript`

you can put this command in a powershell script file (e.g. yourScript.ps1), then put this powershell script in a cmd script that you can then run at startup. Write this in the cmd file:

`PowerShell pathToYourScript\yourscript.ps1`

Comment: Great idea, but i think powershell has limitations towards using bash. I get errors (I eddited my post for details).

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to directly inplement it. Because windows support it to use linux sub system.

Answer (score 0):

in powershell use:

wsl sh

this starts up the wsl subsystem, not just powershell

Comment: works for cmd shell too (which you use for curl maybe?)